# Adding a <br> tag in a string after each 12 digit number

Tags: php, hl7

I've a string from an HL7 message (lab results) and need to add a line break 
 after each 12 digit number.

Example string:

```
1    NM    2951-2  S Sodium:  LN     144    mmol/L  mmol/L    135-145       F      201402150533      2    NM    2823-3  S Potassium:  LN     5.6    mmol/L  mmol/L    3.5-5.5    H      F      201402150533      3    NM    2075-0  S Chloride:  LN     103    mmol/L  mmol/L    95-110       F      201402150533
```

As the 12 digit string is a date and timestamp this will change every test.

Comment: You can always use regex.

Comment: Don't you simply mean "How to change newlines to <BR> elements?" - if this is so, I suspect the *issue* is actually in *how the data is rendered* (e.g. it's directly thrown in HTML helter skelter). I don't see anything "special" about a 12-digit number, except that it is the end of a line.

Comment: This looks like you put just the content of OBX fields in one long line. Why did you not add the line break after each OBX segment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is a good time to use a regular expression (see [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\d{12}/', '$0<br>', $str);
```

replaces each string of 12 numerical digits, with that same string followed by `<br>`.

Comment: That is perfect. Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. Been banging my head against a wall trying to get that to work.